# private_pub Faye.js is blocked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, faye, private-pub

I adding an instant chat (like gmail chat) in my rails application and I am using private_pub and faye. The app seems to work so far, but users can only see messages after they refresh the page. I inspected the element and it shows that faye.js is being blocked. exact error is

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://....' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://localhost:9292/faye.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Has anyone exeperienced such an error and/or any idea how to work around this? See attached image for a screenshot of the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xniet.png)

Comment: can you post your JS part in application.html.erb it seems your website is build with https but this part alone has an explicit request via http.

Comment: @Coderhs This is the JS part of application.html.erb `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, name: "stripe-key", content: STRIPE_PUBLIC %>`

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser behaviour in the interest of security.

HTTPS pages are blocked from loading non-HTTPS resources like `Javascript`, images and CSS files and will show you that error.

If you must load your page over `HTTPS`, ensure all resources must also be in `HTTPS`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using cloud9 for development. But by default, the gem serves faye.js via localhost url, so I was just wondering if anyone has had this experience and could suggest another walk-around.

Comment: All good. If you're just doing dev, you could switch your main app to HTTP.